# Having a divide by zero in my code

Tags: c++, divide-by-zero

Hes my code and I can't figure out where I'm getting the divide by zero problem.

**mreviewApp.cpp**

```
const int SIZE = 80;
const char DELIMIT = '|';

void parseLine(const char line[], string& title, int& rating);
void stringTrim(char st[]);
void printMrList(std::vector <Mreview> mrList);
Mreview searchTitle(std::vector <Mreview> &mrList, string title);


int main()
 {
  ifstream fin;

  fin.open("rating_list.txt");
  if (fin.fail()) {
    cerr << "Input file opening error.\n";
    exit(1);
  }

  char line[SIZE];
  string title;
  int rating;
  int lineCount = 0;

  std::vector <Mreview> mrList;

  /* Process one line at a time */
  // Read the first line
  fin.getline(line, SIZE);
  stringTrim(line);

  // Process loop
  while (strlen(line) != 0) { 
    parseLine(line, title, rating);
    lineCount++;

    Mreview review = searchTitle(mrList, title);
    review.addScore(rating);

    // Read the next line
    fin.getline(line, SIZE);
    stringTrim(line);
  }

  cout << "** PROCESS DONE. There were " << mrList.size() << " movie titles. **\n\n";

  printMrList(mrList);
  // Close the input file before exit.
  fin.close();

  system("Pause");
  return 0;
}

void parseLine(const char line[], string& title, int& rating)
{
  char s[SIZE], r[SIZE];
  const char *ptr, *temp1;
  char *temp2;

  ptr = strchr(line, DELIMIT);

  if (ptr != NULL) {
    // First grab the title string (until '|').
    temp1 = line;
    temp2 = s;
    while (temp1 != ptr)
      *temp2++ = *temp1++;

    *temp2 = '\0';

    stringTrim(s);
    title = s;

    // Second grab the rating number
    temp1 = ptr+1;
    temp2 = r;
    while (*temp1 != '\0')
      *temp2++ = *temp1++;

    *temp2 = '\0';

    stringTrim(r);
    rating = atoi(r);
  }
  else {
    title = "";
    rating = 0;
  }
}

void stringTrim(char st[])
{
  char* ptr;

  for (ptr = st; *ptr; ptr++) ;
  for (ptr--; *ptr == ' ' && ptr >= st; ptr--) ;
  ptr++;
  *ptr = '\0';

  for (ptr = st; *ptr && *ptr == ' '; ptr++) ;

  if (*ptr && ptr != st) {
    char* ptr2;
    for (ptr2 = st; *ptr; *ptr2++ = *ptr++) ;
    *ptr2 = '\0';
  }
}

void printMrList(std::vector <Mreview> mrList)
{
    std::vector<Mreview>::iterator itr;
    for(itr = mrList.begin(); itr != mrList.end(); itr++) {
        Mreview review = *(itr);
        cout << review.getTitle() << "\t\t" << review.getTotalScore() << "\t\t" << review.aveRating() << endl;
    }
}

Mreview searchTitle(std::vector <Mreview> &mrList, string title)
{
    Mreview review (title); 
    std::vector<Mreview>::iterator itr;
    for(itr = mrList.begin(); itr != mrList.end(); itr++) {
        Mreview r2d2 = *(itr);
        if(review.getTitle() == r2d2.getTitle())
            return r2d2;
    }
    mrList.push_back(review);
    return review;
}
```

**mreview.cpp**

```
Mreview::Mreview(string ttl)
  : title(ttl), totalScore(0), numRatings(0) {}

Mreview::Mreview(string ttl, int score)
  : title(ttl), totalScore(score), numRatings(1) {}
void Mreview::addScore(int score)
{
    this->totalScore += score;
    this->numRatings += 1;
}

double Mreview::aveRating() const
{
    double rating = totalScore/numRatings;
    return rating;
}
```

**mreview.h**

```
#ifndef MREVIEW_H
#define MREVIEW_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Mreview
{
public:
  Mreview(string ttl = "N/A");
  Mreview(string ttl, int firstScore);

  string getTitle() const { return title; }
  int getTotalScore() const { return totalScore; }
  int getNumRatings() const { return numRatings; }

  void addScore(int score);
  double aveRating() const;

private:
  string title;
  int totalScore;
  int numRatings;
};

#endif
```

My problem is that I am unable to figure out what I have to do to fix the problem. I have read the comments and I am still confused.

Comment: Might want to fix your question's syntax there.

Comment: ask Jon SKeet or Scott Hanselman they doesn't have a problem with that

Comment: Hey! You are using Dev-C++ ... guess how I can tell?

Answer (score 7):

You're allocating (and copying!) a vector of `Mreview` objects, **all of which are being constructed with the default ctor**, so `numRatings` defaults to 0, and you are doing nothing to ensure that `aveRating()` is never called on unmodified objects or at the very least protects itself from `numRatings` being 0.

Edit: Easiest fix:

```
double Mreview::aveRating() const { 
    if (numRatings == 0)
        return 0.;
    else 
        return static_cast<double>(totalScore)/numRatings;
}
```

A further fix, IMO, would be to store `Mreview` *pointers* (ideally shared_ptr) in the vector and `new`ing them *when the first score is to be added* rather than earlier.

Comment: I'm just confused on how exactly to fix this issue.

Comment: Do Paul's suggestion. That's the easiest fix. Personally, I wouldn't store this kind of class in a vector without pointers anyway: I'd make the default ctor explicit and only add a new instance of the class to the vector<> when I have a firstScore to put in it.

Comment: Er, rather, Paul's suggestion testing numRatings instead of totalScore. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I only see one actual division operation...

```
double Mreview::aveRating() const { 
   double rating = totalScore/numRatings; 
   return rating; 
}
```

...so is it there?

Answer (score 3):

When looking for divide by zero problems, look for / and % operators.  I see only one / in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Not the divide by zero error, but...

```
double Mreview::aveRating() const
{
    double rating = totalScore/numRatings;
    return rating;
}
```

You are taking two integer values and storing it in a double without typecasting... you have to cast either totalScore or numRatings to a double like:

```
double Mreview::aveRating() const
{
    double rating = (double)totalScore/numRatings;
    return rating;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you run it in a debugger and let it tell you where the trap occurred?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if the length of the line is 0 after trimming, then `printMrList()` can be called without `review.addScore()` being called first.  In that case, `printMrList()` calls `review.aveRating()` which tries to divide `totalScore` by `numRatings`.  Both of these values are 0, so a divide by zero error occurs.